# Slow disk when over certain size, but far from full

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, performance

Some months ago, my computer suddenly slowed down. Drastically. It was practically unusable, and took about 20 minutes to boot up and get past login screen.

I opened the Task Manager, and saw it claimed to be using 100% of disk, even though the speeds were less than 1MB/s combined.

After trying lots of possible solutions (see list further down) I eventually just re-installed the machine which fixed the problem.

All good.

Now, the problem occurred again. But this time I noticed it happened right after a Steam download had finished. I tried deleting another game (so not files stored on the newly occupied part of the disk), and immediately the computer ran normally. The problem has been gone since.

Some updates:

- Malware ruled out with Bitdefender
- chkdsk finds no problems
- Speccy (SMART) finds no problems
- Tried disabling SuperFetch

First time it happened was on Windows 10. Second time on Windows 11.

Does someone have experienced a similar problem, and know of a solution? Somehow I suspect some disk management software in Windows is confused about the size of the hard drive. But it's faaaar from full. It's a 2TB drive with roughly 1.5TB free. And it shows the correct size and usage when opening "My PC", so it wouldn't be all Windows systems which are confused.

Have I done something wrong with configuring the disk? I would really appreciate to be able to use more than 25% of my hard drive :D

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the make and model of the drive?

Comment: (1) Search the Event Viewer for disk error messages. (2) Verify the disk's SMART status using a product such as [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy). (3) Run `chkdsk`, (4) Test Windows integrity by running [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html). (5) Run an antivirus deep scan of the computer.

Comment: @Mokubai I checked the invoice and msinfo32, and it just says "2 TB PCS 2,5" SSD, SATA 6 Gb" - I don't know if that's useful?

Comment: @harrymc Where in Event Viewer would you suggest I look? SMART in Speccy looks completely fine. chkdsk also found no problems. A/V scan also found 0 problems.

Comment: In the Event Viewer, just look for warnings that may pertain to the disk. Scan also with [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/). Does the slowdown occur when booting in Safe mode (note no internet)? What is the exact model of the disk (see label) and does Speccy agree about the size of the disk?

Comment: @harrymc - are you thinking what I'm thinking - it isn't really a 2TB SSD ?

Comment: @Tetsujin: Yes - one possibility is that this a cheap forgery.

Comment: @harrymc - it was my first thought, as it's displaying behaviour very similar to a full SSD.

Comment: post screenshot CrystalDiskInfo so we can see SMART and exact drive model.

Comment: I would do a disk test with Victoria, unfortunately you will have to use google translate as the website is in Russian.  You want to have all green colored squares, the more you see other colors the worst off your drive.